# How to cut files on Finder on Mac OSX 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: macos, finder, osx-mavericks

I can't cut files on Mac OSX 10.9 Mavericks after upgrade. I can only copy and delete them. Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: You could never cut files in Finder. Do you mean copying and then moving?

Comment: Lokk to the Edit - Cut menu item.

Comment: There has never been such an item in OS X' Finder. You must have installed some third party add on for that. Your question is a little vague…

Comment: Never? Cut as in apple-x. The grayed out option you see when you highlight a file and select Edit from the file menu. I've been using it for years and all on different Macs I did and didn't configure myself. I don't remember having to install anything extra.

Comment: Yet another reason to dislike the Mac

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to mark a file for copying or moving, change directory, then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to move the previously marked file. This only requires OS X 10.8 or so.

Comment: I've been using OS X for over 8 years, and I always just assumed this was not possible.  THANK YOU.  Mind blown!

Comment: For those new to Macs (like myself), the **Opt** key is the **alt** key.

Comment: WTF Apple?!?  Why have an alternative that is so different from the standard that the rest of the world knows?  Hmmpf.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel You're asking me, and not Apple, here. But let me try anyway: Because "cutting" files is very different from cutting text (cut twice in a row and see what happens), so the established "standard", viewed critically, makes little sense and is just learned behavior. IMO this is the reason this hasn't existed for a few decades, and was only implemented recently, deliberately not mirroring cut/paste of text.

Comment: @DanielBeck Sorry for implying that I was asking you the question. I was ranting by asking a rhetorical question aimed at Apple in vein hope that they might happen to see my (and many others) complaints and allow developer API hooks in Finder rather than disable TotalFinder and XtraFinder with System Integrity Protection (damn them!)

That said, you are arguing pedantics over pragmatism. Windows has proven for well over 2 decades that in practice people have no problem with any perceived inconsistency with Cut & Paste on text vs. on files (or on cells in Excel, for  that matter!)

Answer (score 1):

TotalFinder for Mavericks enables the cut functionality.

Comment: Another alternative is [Yoink](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/yoink/id457622435?mt=12)

Comment: TotalFinder stopped working with El Capitan and development has been stopped. http://blog.binaryage.com/el-capitan-update/